# Detect CTRL key pressed in Java without any event passed

Tags: java, keyboard

I'm developing an extension in Java for a native Windows application. My extension is launched by clicking on a button in the host application. I've been asked to provide a different behavior for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click action, but I don't have access to the mouse event since it comes from a non-Java application and the method that I must implement is parameterless.

I can use Swing and anything else in the JDK (Java 6). What I need is a way to test whether the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is down at the beginning of my code.

Comment: Why not have the native application provide you with details of the launch event, or change the launch action accordingly

Comment: The native application is not under our control. We purchased it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is impossible for Java to check state if currently key is pressed without previously installing keylistener and manually catching specified key.

Because you said that that you are developing a native windows application:

You can use JNI to access custom code in C++ and use windows method "GetKeyState" which gives you functionality you seem to want.